# Using LinkedList to access a get method

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

Direct is a class that contains 2 get methods and one of them is `getName()`. 
In the following code, I am using an array and it works correctly.

But if I want to store it in a `LinkedList` instead of an array, how do I iterate and reach the `getName()` method. I am able to iterate fine if is just a list of common primitives such as Strings but in this case where it is a list of class, I am confused on how to reach the `getName()` method. Thanks for helping.

```
private LinkedList<Direct> directList= new LinkedList();
private ListIterator<Direct> iterator = directList.listIterator(); 
private Direct[] direct = new Direct[100];

private int find(String name){
    for (int x=0; x < direct.length; x++){
        if (direct[x] != null)
            if (direct[x].getName().equals(name)){
                return x;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `directList.get(i)`. But you shouldn't use the index based `get()` method with `LinkedList` as it's **very** slow. Instead, you should use an iterator (or a for each loop, which is essentially the same):

```
int cnt = 0;
List<Direct> list = new LinkedList<>();
for (Direct d : list) {
    if (name.equals(d.getName())) {
        return cnt;
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

With an iterator:

```
for (Iterator<Direct> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Direct d = it.next();
    if(name.equals(d.getName())){
        System.out.println("matches");
    }
}
```

In Java 8 you can also use the following solution (which will be slower, as it filters the entire list):

```
Direct d = list.stream().filter(direct -> direct.getName().equals(name)).findFirst();
```

Comment: I would like to use the iterator way but by doing that, I am unable to obtain the index value of the matching position.

Comment: Ah, then why not simply introduce an int variable and count yourself? This is still way better than using index based access on a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways:

```
// generally easier to read if you don't need access to the iteration number.
for( Direct d : directList )
{
    d.getName();
    // ...
}
```

or use [`List#get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get%28int%29) method (Although this is valid, since you are using a `LinkedList` this solution is `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)` it shouldn't be used.)

```
for( int i = 0; i < directList.size(); ++i )
{
    directList.get(i).getName();
}
```

Comment: You should not iterate a `LinkedList`using `for (... get(i) ...)`. You shall use `iterator()` instead (for performance reason, because N iterations are required to get to the _Nth_ element)

Comment: For the 2nd way, is there any particular reason why you pre-increment i instead of post-increment?

Comment: @user3439075 habit. post-increment has to keep a temporary variable of the value before the increment to return while pre-increment does not. But that would probably be compiled away anyway. As @xav said, you shouldn't use `get` with a linked list since it is slow: `O(n)` vs `O(n^2)`

Comment: Got it thanks. Just pondering on how to still obtain the index value of the matching position while using an iterator.

Comment: @user3439075 You can use an iterator and iteration index: `int i = 0; for( Direct d : list ){ ...; ++i; }`

Comment: That is still effective in terms of performance compared to ListIterator?

Comment: @user3439075 technically no, as you are doing one more operation per loop (`++i`), but it will still be `O(n)`

Comment: Hm ok. To clarify, am I right to say - if I want to get the index value, I have no choice but to skip using iterator and use the normal for loop.

Comment: @user3439075 if the iterator is implemented sanely for a list, then no. you can do as I said before, have an int that gets update each iteration.